# Bypassing Validation Rules for User/Profile with Apex Test Code

Tags: apex, validation-rule

I have some legacy test classes that I'm updating. One of these get's hung-up by a validation rule that requires a record only be changed by certain users/profile.

Now, I understand that test classes are run by the system and not as any particular users - is this correct? If so, can I structure the validation rule to allow system / test class to make the changes?

Thanks in advance!

Dane

Answer (score 7):

The unit tests run as the user that started the test. You can also use the [System.runAs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) method to run the code as different users. See the example below which creates a new user and then runs the code as that user.

```
@isTest                   
private class TestRunAs {
   public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
      // Setup test data
      // This code runs as the system user
      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
      User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

      System.runAs(u) {
         // The following code runs as user 'u' 
         System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
         System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom setting and add the profile or user for whom this validation rule need to be passed and refer that in the validation rule as condition, so it can fire for other users except those included in custom setting

Comment: I've read about this as a solution. However, I might as well just add myself as exempt from the validation rule itself. I thing the RunAs might be more permanent in the long-term (unless the validation rule changes). Thanks for your response!

Comment: We've been contemplating this option for a while now and its good for specific use cases like: (1) Temporary disablement for bulk DML or (2) Temporary disablement for getting past deployments that have failed existing test methods.
IMPORTANT:  We only update the custom setting to disable only during these or similar use cases and its for a very narrow window of time.  We also only enable for the System Administrator profile so as not to impact any business user functionality.  Lastly, we never leave enabled!